# Bootstrap-Wizard: onPrevious not working with if index?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, web-deployment, twitter-bootstrap-wizard

I am using a bootstrap wizard in one of my applications but i noticed when i try and use the index position of the tabs to achieve a certain goal it would only work with the next button, not the previous button. onPrevious works, just wont go into the if statement.

```
$('#rootwizard').bootstrapWizard({
        'tabClass': 'bwizard-steps',
        onTabClick: function(tab, navigation, index) {
            return false;
        },
        onNext: function(tab, navigation, index) {

            alert('this works');

            if (index === 1) {
                alert('this works');
            }

        },
        onPrevious: function(tab, navigation, index) {

            alert('this works');

            if (index === 2) {
                alert('this doesn't work');
            }
        }
    });
```

My goal is specific with the 2nd tab previous button, but it simply wont work despite the code being exactly the same as the onNext witch works perfectly. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

if you have two tabs the index are 0 and 1 , not 1 and 2

index has the value of the tab where you are going to be, not the tab where you are